# How do I access STATUS value in php?

Tags: json

This is the API ulr response. I want to print the Status value(php). I have coded everything. Getting responses in mt page. I dont need the Curl coding. I wrote all. I just not able to access the "status". The "domain.com" is dynamic.

```
{"domain.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}
```

Comment: Show the code and explain what "just not able to access" means; what error you get, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_decode('{"domain.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}');
```

Will give you:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["domain.com"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["classkey"]=>
    string(6) "domcno"
    ["status"]=>
    string(9) "available"
  }
}
```

Since your property (domain.com) is dynamic you can do something like this to convert it to an array (use `array_values` to change array key to index).

```
$data = array_values((array) json_decode('{"domain.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}');

$status = $data[0]->status; // 'available'
```